# From where i can get multi temporal satelite pictures

Tags: dataset, satellite, satellite-image

I am working on change detection on remote sensing imagery. I want to know from I can get multi-temporal satellite images i.e over a time span of a year I want to have satellite imagery of same places with the same resolution

Comment: Stackoverflow is not the right place for your question. See the description of the dataset-tag: _If you are looking for a freely available dataset for any purpose, please consider asking your question on https://opendata.stackexchange.com._

Comment: Check https://earthengine.google.com/datasets/